# Two functions using the same variable, both do not overwrite its original

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables

I have two functions,

```
        function totald(){
            a=a+ns
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML ="number of collected stuff = "+ a ;
        }
        setInterval(totald, 1000);
```

and

```
        function subtractd(x){
            a=a-x
        }
```

before i made a variable var a=0 and now i need it so both functions use this variable and the variable needs to be "up to date" every sec. Whenever i use it they both have their own variable a and use it separately.

Comment: From your question it's not clear what you are after actually!!!

Comment: i want both functions to use the same variable, instead of them using diffrent variables. Is there a way for a function to overwrite var a = 0 so the  other function uses that variable instead of the one that it got a few sec ago.

Comment: Both functions are sharing `a`. It's in the global scope. However `totald` is on an interval. How is `subtractd` called?

Comment: <button id="button1" onclick="cps(1);subtractd(1)">+1</button>
with this button and cps is calculating stuff per second

Comment: @QuietDaniel: Please show us the whole script, including the declaration of the `a` variable. Maybe it's not in scope for your functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the "document" for global variables :

```
document.a = 20;
function totald(){
    document.a=document.a+ns
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML ="number of collected stuff = "+ document.a ;
}
setInterval(totald, 1000); 
function subtractd(x){
    document.a = document.a - x
}
```

Comment: That's not a scope, and no you should definitely not use `document` for arbitrary properties.